# jquery .load() not work mount table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having trouble mounting a table using .load () jquery.

My table is as follows.

```
<table id="table_test">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> COLUNA 1 </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>


    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My file assembles the following output.

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <span> Value 2</span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I'm using the following function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
         $('# table_test'). load ('modules/a/processa.php? opt = 2');
});
</ script>
```

However it is unable to mount the rows in the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/marcoscarraro/7NsNu/

Any suggestions?

Comment: you have a syntax error, `($` is backwards. Next, you need to target the .load at the tbody, not the table.

Comment: @KevinB sorry it was a mistake when write. How can I do to achieve then the element <tbody>?

Comment: Note: I rolled back the edit because it could potentially be the source of your errors. As xivo mentions, it's full of syntax errors. These should be fixed in the answers, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with **$**.

This should work `$('#table_test').load('modules/a/processa.php?opt=2');`.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake when write.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few typos/syntax errors in your question.  You can try this below.  I'm not sure what your data returns, but I hope it does return text properly.  Let me know if this works.

HTML Structure:

```
<table id="table_test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> COLUNA 1 </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_test tbody').load("modules/a/processa.php?opt=2", 
                                function(response, status, xhr) {
     if (status == "error") {
         var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
         alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
     }
  });
});
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QztST/3/

Comment: XIVO.

Thanks for the feedback.
But not working.

I'm using firebug and even I do not return any error, it shows that the page load processa.php?opt=2

Comment: When you load "modules/a/processa.php?opt=2" from the browser do you get that TR in return?

Comment: I updated my fiddle and answer to perhaps assist you in viewing the possible browser error.

Comment: If I put <div id="test"></ div> and change the js to
$(document).ready (function () {
     $('#test').load ('modules/a/processa.php?opt=2');
});

the page displays the result, but out of order, above <table>.


http://jsfiddle.net/marcoscarraro/7NsNu/3/

Comment: Well, thats because you don't have the table row and cell tags.

Comment: I do not present error.

If I processes the page normally module / a / processa.php? Opt = 2 the result is this.

<tr>
  <td>
   <span> Value 1 </ span>
  </ td>
</ tr>

<tr>
  <td>
   <span> Value 2 </ span>
  </ td>
</ tr>

<tr>
  <td>
   <span> Value 3 </ span>
  </ td>
</ tr>

Comment: Update your question so I can see it better.  The comments are rather difficult to make out.

Comment: xivo Now it's more verbose?

Comment: Your javascript/jquery seems to be fine.  I have a feeling your code isn't loading properly.  Perhaps you could try using the $.ajax function or $.get.
Here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/Lbfwf/

Comment: XIVO.

It did not work. I think the outlet will be developing a json to load these values.

Comment: XIVO, we had a breakthrough.
I'm using jeasyui.com especially its plugin "easyui-datagrid" he has the ability to dynamically load a arquido, but this information has to be in JSON format, what I did was state the "date-options" the parameter "url: "js now is processing the information and setting the table.

Comment: Good Day,

Sorry for the delay.

I solved the problem by creating a table dynamically with jquery. Something was conflicting with the plugin "jquery-easyui." Demodo not allowed me to do the load.

Thank you all for the help.